# Synonym suggestion: [int] and [integer]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Both [integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer) and [int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int) have exactly the same use case as far as I can tell, and both tags have exactly the same usage guidance:

> Use this tag for questions about using, storing, or manipulating integers.

They both have roughly the same number of questions (~9.4k), but it makes sense to me that [integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer) should be the master tag as it isn't an abbreviation. [int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int) has a more detailed tag wiki, but that could be copied across. I've [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/integer/synonyms) the synonym should anyone who meets the requirements wish to vote on it.

This would also match precedent ([str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/str) is a synonym of [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string), [dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dict) is a synonym of [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary))

Comment: I would argue `int` refers to the data type, `integer` refers to the number type and that the usage guidance is just bad

Comment: In most languages with a type named `int`, it is not a proper integer type because it's a fixed number of bits, and arithmetic can overflow. But the usage guidance for the [tag:int] tag doesn't say anything about fixed width types, and the usage guidance for the [tag:integer] tag doesn't say anything about arbitrarily-large integers. I'd say that the vast proportion of those ~19k existing questions are probably using the two tags to mean the same thing.

Comment: @NickA that was my intuition as well, but consider, for example, [tag:str] and [tag:string], [tag:dict] and [tag:dictionary].

Comment: @CDJB `str` and `string` should be the same thing, though, while `int` is a *programming concept* very directly bound to implementation, while `integer` is a *mathematics concept* that partially overlaps with `int`. The two differ in exactly where you don't want them to - integers are infinite, while int types are very much not. Whether we really need a tag for integers, I'm not sure but from a glance, I'd not say these are the same thing.

Comment: @VLAZ I understand the difference, but as kaya3 points out, in practice these tags have been used interchangeably on over 19k questions because the usage guides are identical. What do you suggest would be a better course of action?

Comment: I'd verify if we actually have some math related questions here that deal with integers. It's a bit unusual, to be honest, since we have *two* other communities for maths - [math.se] and [mathoverflow.se]. Still, we do have the [tag:math] tag which means *some* questions not directly related to the programming construct `int` might be around and maybe there are some libraries/languages/something that doesn't have capped integer values. Or something else I can't think of right now. Basically, we have to verify if we really need two tags or one.

Comment: So, I did a [quick check for `math` + `integer` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math+integer) and there does seem to be at least one that isn't bound to the data type: [Mapping two integers to one, in a unique and deterministic way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/919612). I just looked at the first few based on votes and this one was actually number 1. Some of the rest could really go either way, but some were specifically about int type limitations. So, there is *some* case to be done for the maths integer. Not sure how big that case is.